# Continent names and choropleth maps

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I am working with ISO-3 names of the countries. Below you can see one example.I want to use this data for Choropleth map.

```
    datar <- data.frame(GEO = c("GR","AZ","TR","GA","IR"),
                        Value = c(0.5560,0.323,0.2140,0.312,0.0225),
                        search_countries = factor(c("Greece","Azerbaijan","Turkey","Georgia","Iran")),
                        countries = c("Greece","Azerbaijan","Turkey","Georgia","Iran")
    )
    
map <- map_data('world', region = datar$search_countries)
```

The code's last line allows me to draw a Choropleth map. Now I want to have an additional column with the `continent names` for each country next to the column subregion.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and to have a continent name for each country on the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to add a column containing the relevant continents for each country in your dataframe?

Here we can get the country and continent names using the raster package then join them onto your dataframe :)

```
country.codes <- raster::ccodes()

map.continents <- left_join(map, country.codes, by = c('region' = 'NAME')) %>% 
  select(all_of(colnames(map)), continent)
```